# divide a period in two which overlaps with other period

Tags: c#, algorithm

Can you suggest me an algo for this problem please, I have a liste of periods with their prices:
[image]

I want to divide periods like this:

[image]

in the end we will have this list:
[image]

is there any suggestion abou this please.

```cs
private IList<Price> DevisePriceByPeriod(List<Price> prixs)
{
    var priceOrdered = prixs.OrderByDescending(x => x.EndDate - x.StartDate).ThenBy(x => x.StartDate).ToList();
    var pricesCopy = priceOrdered.GetRange(0, prixs.Count());
    var toto = new List<(Guid p1, Guid p2)>();
    var pricesTreated = new List<Price>();
    foreach (var price in priceOrdered)
    {
        var StartDate = price.StartDate;
        var EndDate = price.EndDate;
        foreach (var priceCopied in pricesCopy)
        {

            if (priceCopied.Id != price.Id && !toto.Any(x => x.p1 == price.Id && x.p2 == priceCopied.Id)
                && DateHelper.EstChevauchementPeriodes(
                    StartDate,
                    EndDate,
                    priceCopied.StartDate,
                    priceCopied.EndDate))
            {
                if (StartDate == priceCopied.StartDate && EndDate > priceCopied.EndDate)
                {
                    var priceNewPeriod = new Price
                    {
                        Id = price.Id,
                        StartDate = StartDate,
                        EndDate = priceCopied.EndDate,
                        Value = price.Value,
                    };
                    StartDate = new DateTime(priceCopied.EndDate.Year, priceCopied.EndDate.Month, priceCopied.EndDate.Day).AddDays(1);
                    if (!pricesTreated.Any(x => x.Id == priceNewPeriod.Id
                       && x.StartDate == priceNewPeriod.StartDate && x.EndDate == priceNewPeriod.EndDate))
                    {
                        pricesTreated.Add(priceNewPeriod);
                    }
                }
                else if (StartDate.Date < priceCopied.StartDate && EndDate == priceCopied.EndDate)
                {
                    var priceNewPeriod = new Price
                    {
                        Id = price.Id,
                        StartDate = priceCopied.StartDate,
                        EndDate = EndDate,
                        Value = price.Value,
                    };
                    EndDate = new DateTime(priceCopied.StartDate.Year, priceCopied.StartDate.Month, priceCopied.StartDate.Day, 23, 59, 59).AddDays(-1);
                    if (!pricesTreated.Any(x => x.Id == priceNewPeriod.Id
                       && x.StartDate == priceNewPeriod.StartDate && x.EndDate == priceNewPeriod.EndDate))
                    {
                        pricesTreated.Add(priceNewPeriod);
                    }
                }

                else if (StartDate.Date > priceCopied.StartDate && EndDate > priceCopied.EndDate)
                {
                    var priceNewPeriod = new Price
                    {
                        Id = price.Id,
                        StartDate = StartDate,
                        EndDate = priceCopied.EndDate,
                        Value = price.Value,
                    };
                    StartDate = new DateTime(priceCopied.EndDate.Year, priceCopied.EndDate.Month, priceCopied.EndDate.Day).AddDays(1);
                    if (!pricesTreated.Any(x => x.Id == priceNewPeriod.Id
                                               && x.StartDate == priceNewPeriod.StartDate && x.EndDate == priceNewPeriod.EndDate))
                    {
                        pricesTreated.Add(priceNewPeriod);
                    }
                }

                else if (StartDate.Date < priceCopied.StartDate && EndDate < priceCopied.EndDate)
                {
                    var priceNewPeriod = new Price
                    {
                        Id = price.Id,
                        StartDate = StartDate,
                        EndDate = new DateTime(priceCopied.StartDate.Year, priceCopied.StartDate.Month, priceCopied.StartDate.Day, 23, 59, 59).AddDays(-1),
                        Value = price.Value,
                    };
                    StartDate = new DateTime(priceCopied.StartDate.Year, priceCopied.StartDate.Month, priceCopied.StartDate.Day);
                    if (!pricesTreated.Any(x => x.Id == priceNewPeriod.Id
                                            && x.StartDate == priceNewPeriod.StartDate && x.EndDate == priceNewPeriod.EndDate))
                    {
                        pricesTreated.Add(priceNewPeriod);
                    }
                }

                else if (StartDate.Date >= priceCopied.StartDate && EndDate <= priceCopied.EndDate)
                {
                    var priceNewPeriod = new Price
                    {
                        Id = price.Id,
                        StartDate = StartDate,
                        EndDate = EndDate,
                        Value = price.Value,
                    };
                    //StartDate = new DateTime(priceCopied.StartDate.Year, priceCopied.StartDate.Month, priceCopied.StartDate.Day);
                    if (!pricesTreated.Any(x => x.Id == priceNewPeriod.Id
                                            && x.StartDate == priceNewPeriod.StartDate && x.EndDate == priceNewPeriod.EndDate))
                    {
                        pricesTreated.Add(priceNewPeriod);
                    }
                }

                else if (StartDate.Date < priceCopied.StartDate && EndDate > priceCopied.EndDate)
                {
                    var priceNewPeriod = new Price
                    {
                        Id = price.Id,
                        StartDate = StartDate,
                        EndDate = new DateTime(priceCopied.StartDate.Year, priceCopied.StartDate.Month, priceCopied.StartDate.Day, 23, 59, 59).AddDays(-1),
                        Value = price.Value,
                    };
                    StartDate = new DateTime(priceCopied.StartDate.Year, priceCopied.StartDate.Month, priceCopied.StartDate.Day);
                    if (!pricesTreated.Any(x => x.Id == priceNewPeriod.Id
                                            && x.StartDate == priceNewPeriod.StartDate && x.EndDate == priceNewPeriod.EndDate))
                    {
                        pricesTreated.Add(priceNewPeriod);
                    }
                    var PrixNouvellePeriode2 = new Price
                    {
                        Id = price.Id,
                        StartDate = StartDate,
                        EndDate = priceCopied.EndDate,
                        Value = price.Value,
                    };
                    if (!pricesTreated.Any(x => x.Id == PrixNouvellePeriode2.Id
                                            && x.StartDate == PrixNouvellePeriode2.StartDate && x.EndDate == PrixNouvellePeriode2.EndDate))
                    {
                        pricesTreated.Add(PrixNouvellePeriode2);
                    }
                    StartDate = new DateTime(priceCopied.EndDate.Year, priceCopied.EndDate.Month, priceCopied.EndDate.Day).AddDays(1);

                    var PrixNouvellePeriode3 = new Price
                    {
                        Id = price.Id,
                        StartDate = StartDate,
                        EndDate = EndDate,
                        Value = price.Value,
                    };

                    if (!pricesTreated.Any(x => x.Id == PrixNouvellePeriode3.Id
                    && x.StartDate == PrixNouvellePeriode3.StartDate && x.EndDate == PrixNouvellePeriode3.EndDate))
                    {
                        pricesTreated.Add(PrixNouvellePeriode3);
                    }
                }
                if (!toto.Any(x => x.p1 == price.Id && x.p2 == priceCopied.Id))
                    toto.Add(new(price.Id, priceCopied.Id));

            }

        }
    }

    return pricesTreated;
}
```

Comment: _"I have try my algo but it doesn't cover all cases."_ - and you're asking us to improve it without seeing it?

Comment: I put it but it doens't let me to valid the post

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: it says that there alot of code, what I'm asking is some ideas about this problem, I dont know why you vote down on my post :( I tired to explain well my problem

Comment: Also, it would be better if you could describe the splitting rules as text, and use images as illustration.

Comment: I dont lie anyway Im just telling you what happened, have share my code here https://www.codepile.net/pile/QJMzEEWb

Comment: Thank you for providing your code. I have edited it into your question.

Comment: Your second image is wrong, btw. 8/1/22 00:00 is < 8/1/22 23:59 by 23:59. The next bigger minute would be 9/1/22 00:00

Comment: So is your rule that if a period overlaps the start or end date of another period then it should be split up?

Comment: And what shall be the price in overlaps? The highest price Id? I guess, they need to be unique?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar exactly, like that in the end I can add up prices by period

Comment: @Fildor when we split up a period its price doesnt change, we just make a new endDate and create a new period with same price and Id ( new startdate)

Comment: Then you do not have unique prices. You will end up with the the same period, twice or more times with each a different price. How would you then pick the correct one?

Comment: @Fildor yes the objectif is that in the end I can add up prices by same period

Comment: OK. I don't get it. Maybe that's me.

Comment: @Fildor thank you for your effort, I'm gonna add more details of the result that I want

Comment: Try splitting your logic into smaller pieces, and writing unit tests to confirm each piece works. Then, write an integration test with all bits of logic working together to validate your expected output for a given input. Then you can rule out problems with the algorithm at every step.

Comment: As a side note, it's almost always better to model periods of time like this with *inclusive* start and *exclusive* end points. In your current model, you're required to know exactly what precision is being used to represent times, or if you have ignored that, maybe you're missing events that happen at 23:59:59.433. It's easier to just use the following midnight and just use a `<` comparison rather than `<=`.

Comment: (It's also easier to find periods that precisely abut one another since the end point of one will be precisely equal to the start point of the next, rather than you having to compute an offset)

Answer (score 1):

If you switch to representing periods of time with an inclusive start date and exclusive end date, many operations working with these periods will be easier.

For instance, we're trying to construct a set of non-overlapping periods synthesized from a group of overlapping periods. If these all have the same form (being a datetime at midnight) then it's easy to construct a list of when transitions occur.

In turn, if we sort that set of transitions and pair them of (first with second, second with third, etc) then that already gives us the set of non-overlapping periods.

We can then take each of those periods, find prices from the original list that overlap with that period and construct new price classes from these:

```
public class Price
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public static List<Price> SampleData => new List<Price>()
    {
        new Price() { StartDate = new DateTime(2022, 4, 1), EndDate = new DateTime(2022, 8, 2), Value = 1 },
        new Price() { StartDate = new DateTime(2022, 8, 1), EndDate = new DateTime(2022, 12, 1), Value = 2 },
        new Price() { StartDate = new DateTime(2022, 5, 1), EndDate = new DateTime(2022, 10, 31), Value = 3 },
        new Price() { StartDate = new DateTime(2022, 3, 1), EndDate = new DateTime(2022, 7, 1), Value = 4 }
    };

    public static List<Price> DevisePriceByPeriod(List<Price> prices)
    {
        var distinctEndpoints = prices.SelectMany(a => new[] { a.StartDate, a.EndDate })
                                 .Distinct().OrderBy(d=>d).ToList();
        var distinctPeriods = distinctEndpoints.Zip(distinctEndpoints.Skip(1));

        return distinctPeriods
                  .SelectMany(period => prices.Where(pr => pr.StartDate < period.Second && period.First < pr.EndDate)
                                              .Select(pr => new { period = period, price = pr }))
            .Select(a => new Price { StartDate = a.period.First, EndDate = a.period.Second, Value = a.price.Value }).ToList();
    }
}
```

No special cases need to be considered here to get the overlaps.

Note also that I've supplied your sample inputs back to you (adjusted based on my above comments) as *runnable code*. That is much preferred over sharing sample data as *images* that cannot be copied and pasted into code editors.